# How to display the size of single emails?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I would like to be able to see the size of every email in my Thunderbird. I know how to check the [size of a mail folder](http://www.bhatt.id.au/blog/display-size-of-mail-folders-in-mozilla-thunderbird/) but not for a single mail.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To choose columns, **click on the icon which appears at the right edge of the column headings**. You'll be shown a drop-down menu of columns; the headings with checkmarks are the ones that are currently shown in your mail folders.

Select Size.

[image]