# How to display the size of single emails in Outlook 2007/2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm having problems with a GMail account used over IMAP. The problem is that inbox is full and there is no space left. After deleting about 11000 of oldest mails, there were only a few hundred left and they take up  more than 70% of mailbox. I'm looking for a nice way to sort mails by size so that the largest may be deleted. I found way explained in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/79591/how-to-display-the-size-of-single-emails) question, but it's related to Thunderbird. So what I'm asking is: Is there and easy way to sort mails by size in Outlook 2007 or 2010?

While I know that one possible solution to this problem is to install Thunderbird, user of the GMail account is someone else and she is a fan of Outlook, so I'd rather find a way to do this without installing Thunderbird.

I also know that I can click on the column which shows size of mails, but this way mails come sorted by dates and sizes. Is there any way to just sort them by sizes without sorting them by dates?

Comment: I am always frightened at anybody who can fill up that much email.  (My Gmail storage is currently ~7.5GB).  Outlook tends to choke and die on PST files much larger than that anyway - caveat emptor!

Comment: @Shinrai I too was shocked when I saw that. Looks like there's a feature in 2007 office programs to automatically send status updates by e-mail. They are often around 1 MiB in size and are very numerous (every time the other guy saves a file, status update is mailed).

Comment: Oh, yikes, that would do it!  That's pretty good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of the list of emails should all of the relevant headers. Right-click on them anywhere, then from the menu choose **Arrange By** and choose **Customise Current View**. (This is also available from the menu bar under: View - Arrange By - Current View- Customise Current View)

From here remove any dates from the **Group by** and **Sort** sections, make sure the size field is under sort and press **OK**.

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the size column so that the little triangle appears in the column title, then it will be sorted by size the way you want.  I believe it might sort by date for e-mails with the same size, but this shouldn't matter for you as the e-mails are sorted by size first.  Also, you can use the [Mailbox Cleanup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/manage-your-mailbox-size-with-mailbox-cleanup-HP003088523.aspx) option in Outlook to search for the biggest e-mails.